# UWSGI SIGINT/SIGQUIT received

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to use nginx with uwsi.

I wrote uwsgi ini file and test it with uwsgi --ini site.ini

Everything works fine.

But when I try to run the site I got the following error (from log file):

```
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads$
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1a297d0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 800360 bytes (781 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1a297d0 pid: 177$
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17715)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17718, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 17719, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 17720, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 17721, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 17722, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 17723, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 17724, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 17725, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 17726, cores: 1)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
worker 5 buried after 1 seconds
worker 6 buried after 1 seconds
worker 7 buried after 1 seconds
worker 8 buried after 1 seconds
```

Why do I get SIGINT automatically?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this

Comment: Didn't find any adequate solution.